# What can I do to print all the data of that particular option from the table in the Database?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I have a dropdown list, taking its options from database. Can I know what can be done to fetch all the details of that particular option?
 NOTE: I have used Laravel all along

```
 <select class="form-control select-search" name="selectedUser" id="selectedUser" required style="width: 200px;">
   @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}" class="text-capitalize">{{ $user->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: Please describe more your problem. Which option?

Comment: The options i.e., _users_ are fetched from database to the dropdown. Once I select a user, I want the data of the _user_ to be viewed. Such as _userID_ or _userLocation_ etc

Comment: When you fetch user you have retrieved all the user data. As you said when select a particular user shows their details then you should be using jquery.

Comment: you can send an ajax request to fetch the information of that user from backend.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon can I know with a small example?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya can I know how a jquery can be used? Cuz I'm new to this :/

Comment: ok I will post answer

Comment: @RevanthKumar I have posted an answer. For using jquery many ways to achieve your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the following steps for ajax request.

Route

```
Route::any( '/user-data/{id}', 'UserController@getUser' );
```

In the controller file:

```
public function getUser( $id ){

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    return json_encode($user);
}
```

In view blade

```
<select class="form-control select-search" name="selectedUser" id="selectedUser" required style="width: 200px;">
     @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}" class="text-capitalize">{{ $user->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
<div class="user-details">
     <div class="user-id"></div>
   <div class="user-location"></div>
</div>


$( '#selectedUser' ).change( function() {
   var userid = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({

    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
     type:'GET',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     url: '/user-data/'+userid,        
     success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $('.user-id').html(data.id);
       $('.user-location').html(data.id);
     }
 });
});
```

Comment: I think I understood the logic and it returns the ID. However the console shows a error stating **POST http://localhost/user-data/14 404 (Not Found)**  14 here is the id of the selected user. Should the **user-data** be the URL to my databse?

Comment: @RevanthKumar I have updated my answer, please check.

Comment: @RevanthKumar You can directly check user data to find or fail using  `http://localhost/user-data/14` in browser new tab.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its proper now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send an ajax request to fetch information from the backend. Here is a simple example for you.

(Assume you have jQuery installed already.)

```
<select class="form-control select-search" id="mySelect" name="selectedUser" id="selectedUser" required style="width: 200px;">
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}" class="text-capitalize">{{ $user->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<input type="text" id="userId" readonly>
```

Now the AJAX part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mySelect').change(function(){
        var user = $(this).val();
        var url = '{{ route("fetch.user") }}';
        if (user != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", "user": user},
                success: function(response){                    
                    $('#userId').val(response.userID);                  
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Add the route in your `web.php` file

```
Route::post('fetch/user', 'UserController@getUser')->name('fetch.user');
```

And now in UserController add the `getUser` method

```
public function getUser(Request $request){
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->user);
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

> I have used post request. You can use get request too for this kind of operation.

Comment: I tried this,I just had to change few values here and there. Thank you so much for making me understand.

Comment: Once I get to 15reps. I will surely do it. Its restricting me as of now. :)